# min-width doesn't work with table-layout:fixed

Tags: html, css

I try to use min-width on a td table which has a "table-layout:fixed" caracteristic but it doesn't work :

https://jsfiddle.net/c1qje0us/

HTML :

```
<BODY>
  <TABLE>
    <TR>
      <TD class='test'>test</TD>
      <TD>blablablablablablablablablablablablablablabla</TD>
    </TR>
  </TABLE>
</BODY>
```

CSS :

```
table{
  width:100%;
  table-layout:fixed;
  word-wrap:break-word;
}
.test{
  width: 25%;
  min-width: 100px;
}
```

Have someone an idea to do that?

PS : I need table-layout CSS caracteristic to force the line break when the window's width is small

Comment: table-layout:fixed; will apply width:25%; no matter if a max or a min-width is set else where.

Comment: with a fixed layout all the cells have a fixed width and so there can't be a min or max width that differs from that as then you'd have one cell with two different widths at the same time.

Comment: do you only  need to set 2 containers side by side ?, cause there's others way for the desired output here

Comment: Yes, I understand why min-width doesn't work but I don't find how to change my code to do what I want (width:25%, min-width:100px and forced line break even if the string has no space. And no, I need more than 2 containers side by side, that is just a small call to illustrate my problem.

Comment: take a look at display:flex, use width and min-max-width for cell taht needs control and flex:1; for cells that need to fill up space left. .. be aware that the table-layout will be broken see my update answer below ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if it is to set 2 boxes side by side , flex would do the job for you.

*(added some css to break you words)*

```css
.fixedRow {
  display: flex;
  max-width: 100%;
background:linear-gradient(to right, gray 220px, lightgray 220px); /* check min-width of first-cell */
}
div {
  box-shadow:0 0 0 1px red;
  -ms-word-break: break-all;
  word-break: break-all;
  // Non standard for webkit
  word-break: break-word;
  -webkit-hyphens: auto;
  -moz-hyphens: auto;
  hyphens: auto;

}
.test {
  width: 25%;
  min-width: 220px;
}
.liquid {
  flex: 1;
```

```html
<div class="fixedRow">
  <div class="test">
    Test
  </div>
  <div class="liquid">blablablablablablablablablablablaablablablablaablablablablaablablablablablablablabla
  </div>
</div>
```

example with 3 boxes and 2 rows:

```css
.fixedRow {
  display: flex;
  max-width: 100%;
background:
  linear-gradient(to right, gray 220px, transparent 220px),
  linear-gradient(to left, gray 220px, transparent 220px ) lightgray; /* check min-width of first-cell */
}
div {
  box-shadow:0 0 0 1px red;
  -ms-word-break: break-all;
  word-break: break-all;
  // Non standard for webkit
  word-break: break-word;
  -webkit-hyphens: auto;
  -moz-hyphens: auto;
  hyphens: auto;

}
.test {
  width: 25%;
  min-width: 220px;
}
.liquid {
  flex: 1;
```

```html
<div class="fixedRow">
  <div class="test">
    Test
  </div>
  <div class="liquid">blablablablablablablablablablablaablablablablaablablablablaablablablablablablablabla
  </div>
  <div class="test">
    Test me in full page
  </div>
</div>
<div class="fixedRow">
  <div class="test">
    Test
  </div>
  <div class="liquid">blablablablablablablablablablablaablablablablaablablablablaablablablablablablablabla
  </div>
  <div class="test">
    Test
  </div>
</div>
```